# htaccess que esconde somente diretórios

Tags: htaccess, apache

Eu criei um diretório `assets` a fim de colocar os *assets* do meu projeto.
Até aí tudo bem, contudo, verifiquei que ao digitar na URL `localhost/project/assets`, ele mostra a estrutura do diretório dessa pasta. A fim de impedir essa ação, criei um arquivo `.htaccess` no diretório `assets`:

```
Deny from all
```

Criar o `.htaccess` da forma acima preveniu a visualização do diretório, mas causou um erro: nenhum arquivo, sendo CSS ou JavaScript é carregado desta pasta.

Assim, minha questão é:
Há como esconder somente **os diretórios**, deixando **visíveis** ainda os seus respectivos **arquivos** para a minha própia aplicação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente só com isso no seu arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Leonardo! Funcionou perfeitamente. ^-^

Comment: Por nada. Você pode clicar no tick ("v") abaixo da resposta para que ela seja marcada como aceita. Assim, fica documentado para outros que venham a acessar o site que a resposta solucionou o seu problema.